# setting airflow docker user id

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have set up airflow using docker as described

[Running Airflow in Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#)

Overall i want to achieve that dags and logs files are accessible and owned by a specific  user on the host side. (And eventually exposed as a sambas share.)

I have used the standard yaml docker-compose.yaml and created a ".env" file in the same directory as the docker-compose.yaml where is specify my desired user id on the host:
AIRFLOW_UID=1234

If i start a new container and check configuration:

```
docker compose down
docker compose up
docker exec -it -u airflow docker-airflow-worker-1 env|grep AIRFLOW_UID
```

I see
AIRFLOW_UID=50000

So it seems that the .env file is not read. This means that ownership of the files created in the container looks like this inside the container

```
-rw-r--r--     1 airflow root            0 Mar 20 09:40  x  
-rw-r--r--     1 airflow root            0 Mar 20 09:41  y
-rw-r--r--     1 airflow root            0 Mar 20 10:44  z
```

And like this on the host

```
-rw-r--r--     1 50000 root        0 Mar 20 10:40  x
-rw-r--r--     1 50000 root        0 Mar 20 10:41  y
-rw-r--r--     1 50000 root        0 Mar 20 11:44  z
```

I am running airflow 2.7.3. I have tried a lot of different hacks to solve this problem, but I have returned to the "vanilla" compose and tried to make this work.

I am using a Dockerfile that looks like this

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest-python3.9

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev \
    libffi-dev liblzma-dev git nano less python3-dev&& \
 apt-get clean
USER airflow
```